# A non ideal feature of compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional complex Hilbert space.
Is there a $C^*$  subalgebra $A$ of $B(H)$ such that  $A$ is not an idea but it is $C^*$-isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}$, the algebra of compact opetators?

Comment: Yes, since $H$ is infinite dimensional it is isomorphic to $H\oplus \Bbb C$. Denote the first summand with $H'$ and let $K'$ be all compact operators with image in $H'$ and whose kernel contains $\Bbb C$. This is not an ideal but should be isomorphic as a $C^*$-algebra to $K(H)$.

Comment: @s.harp  Thank you  for your perfect answer. In fact your example is in the form $e\mathbb{K}e$  for  a  large projection $e$, so it is contained in $\mathcal{K}$. But is there an  example of a situation that a  sub algebra $A\subset B(H)$ which is  isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}$ but is not contained  in $\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: You can do something similar. Let $k$ a Hilbertbasis of $H$, then $k\times \Bbb N$ has the same cardinality as $k$ since $H$ is infinite dimensional. In particular $H':=\bigoplus_{i\in k}\ell^2(\Bbb N)_i$ is isomorphic to $H$ having a Hilbert basis indexed by $k\times \Bbb N$ (the subscript $i$ is just to keep track of which summand we are in). For $i,j\in k$ let $P_{ij}: \ell^2(\Bbb N)_i\to \ell^2(\Bbb N)_j$ be the identity isomorphisms, and for $A$ in $K$ let $A_{ij}$ be the matrix coefficients of $A$ in basis $k$. Define
$$\varphi:K\to B(H'),\qquad A\mapsto \sum_{ij\in k}A_{ij}P_{ij}$$

Comment: which should be isometric and thus an isomorphism on its image. The only compact operator in the image is however $0$.